# angularjs scope(the crux): parent child scope having model(with and without 'dot')

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

**Example *WITHOUT* 'dot'**
http://jsfiddle.net/CmXaP/168/

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="parent">
        Parent ctrl value: <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />

        <div ng-controller="child1">
            Child1 ctrl value: <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
                        <div ng-controller="child2">
                            Child2 ctrl value: <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
                        </div>

        </div>

 Parent ctrl value(after child1 ctrl block): {{name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example *WITH* 'dot'**
http://jsfiddle.net/CmXaP/167/

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="parent">
        Parent ctrl value: <input type="text" data-ng-model="user.name" />

        <div ng-controller="child1">
            Child1 ctrl value: <input type="text" data-ng-model="user.name" />
                        <div ng-controller="child2">
                            Child2 ctrl value: <input type="text" data-ng-model="user.name" />
                        </div>

        </div>

 Parent ctrl value(after child1 ctrl block): {{user.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
var ngapp = angular.module('myapp',[]);

ngapp.controller("parent", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
      name : 'anil'
  };
}]);
ngapp.controller("child1", ['$scope', function($scope) {}]);
ngapp.controller("child2", ['$scope', function($scope) {}]);
```

A) In case of without 'dot' (like primitive var in scope)
1. Edit '**Parent** ctrl value' and it will reflect in all other values(child1 and child2) with this value
2. Edit '**Child1** ctrl value' and it will reflect in child2 only
3. Edit '**Child2** ctrl value' and it will reflect in child2 only
4. Now edit '**Parent** ctrl value' and it will reflect in Parent ctrl only

B) In case of with 'dot' (like object in scope)
Follow A)1 to A)4 steps and you will see any changes in any ctrl will reflect in all values

why this is so?

Comment: angularjs version 1.4.7

Comment: Your JavaScrip code should be at least in a script tag...

Comment: i am trying to achieve something like http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html. AngularJS creates child scope using prototypal inheritance, based on that i want to understand the scope creation like i said {{theField}} should be printed as it belongs to parent scope?

Comment: to explain it further, i would like to know how angularjs creates child scope variables when $scope.name vs $scope.user.name is used? Here, I would like to know how 'dot' in model changes the object creation, which is explained in this post http://blog.carbonfive.com/2014/02/11/angularjs-scopes-an-introduction/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular creates a child scope for each controller. Having a dot in the model doesn't change anything to that.

When you enter 'foo' in a field with `ng-model="name"`, here's what angular does with the scope of the current controller:

```
scope.name = 'foo';
```

If there was already a `name` field in the parent scope, it's unaffected. So you end up with

```
parentScope ---> name --> 'some previous value'
scope ---------> name --> 'foo'
```

Now when you enter 'foo' in a field with `ng-model="user.name"`, here's what angular basically does with the scope of the current controller:

```
if (!angular.isDefined(scope.user)) {
    scope.user = {};
}
scope.user.name = 'foo';
```

So, if the parent scope already had a user, with a name attribute having the value 'some previous value', you end up with

```
parentScope --> user ------> name ----> 'foo
                 ^
scope ----------/
```

Why? Because the scope prototypically inherits from the parent scope, so when evaluating `scope.user`, JavaScript doesn't find a `user` attribute on the scope object, so it looks for it on the prototype (the parent scope), and finds it. Both the parent and the child thus share a single user object, and `scope.user.name = 'foo'` changes the name attribute of this shared object.

Comment: thanks JB Nizet for your answer, but basically i was looking for the process flow how it manages the difference with and without 'dot' in model. Kindly please check if my own answer explains better what I have asked for?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with objects being passed by reference. BTW, objects are not passed by reference. References to objects are passed, by value. The difference is that, when there is a dot in the ngModel, nothing is written on the scope. The user field is **read** on the scope (and the protoype chain is thus used to find this field). Once found, the name is written on this user object, as explained in my answer.

Comment: while writing it does not find 'name' in child scope and thus creates it in child scope, why does it not behave the same way in case 'user.name'??? how does it writes to the parent scope?

Comment: It does behave the same way: is user was not defined in the parent scope, then a new user attribute would be added to the current scope. But since user already exists in the parent scope, **reading** it in the child scope finds it in the parent scope. When you write, however, the prototypal chain is not used. I read `scope.user.name = 'foo'` as `scope.getUser.setName('foo')`. get searches in the parent, but set does not.

Comment: so u mean in case of 'name' variable, while writing it does not read but writes, hence no question of going to parent and writes to the current scope?

Comment: I'm saying that reading a field consists in looking for it in the scope, then in the parent, then in the grandparent, etc. until found. But writing a field consists in writing it on the scope directly, without caring if the field exists or not in the parent. So, when executing `scope.name = 'foo'`, it writes name in the scope. But when executing `scope.user.name = 'foo'`, it looks for user in the scope, then in the parent, etc., and when it has found it, it writes name in the found user.

Comment: ok, i understand now :), thanks a bunch, i think this last comment is what i was looking for, which u have explained previously as well. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As we know child scope creation in angularjs is based on prototypal inheritance.
Therefore, while while displaying the values it searches the current scope(child scope) for 'name', here in this case both child scopes does not have any 'name' variable, so it will be read from parent scope and will display in each child scope.

**Basic rule: So reading a value will search the parents if it is not found.**

But while writing a value always writes directly to the object, even if it is also defined higher up.

If one of child1 or child2 tries to write to parent's scope, it will work only on object var(non-primitive) types. The reason for this is that object(non-primitive) types are passed by reference.
In other way when it tries to write normal variable(primitive) it will write into the current scope(in case A) child scope), hence it is not getting reflected in other scopes.