# directive content become empty when select in ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

sorry for the strange title, here is my Problem :
I got an empty array. when a button is clicked, 
its create a new item in the array (array.push) with blank properties :

name: ' ' ,date: ' ' ,user : ' '  ,, phoneNumber: ''

the array is reflected to table, and every item is a new table row as below :

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
<td> <select ng-model ="$parent.rows[$index]" ng-options = "user.name for user in usersDB> </select>
<td><date-picker> </date-picker> </td>
<td>{{$parent.rows.user}}</td>
<td> {{$parent.rows.phoneNumber}}</td>
</tr>
```

my problem is, when I choose a date from a date-picker directive,and after that change the user from the ng-option, the date is become empty . how can i fix that?

my date-picker directive :

```
app.directive('datePicker',function(){
return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: true, 
          template: '<input ui-date-format = "dd/MM/yyyy" type=text uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model = "$parent.rows[$index].date" is-open ="status.opened" ng-click="open($event)" ',

}

});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

in such cases, please try to post sample fiddle to assist you faster. But in most of such cases one should always be careful about parent child scope comcept, which is explained in this link

[angularjs scope(the crux): parent child scope having model(with and without 'dot')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820473/angularjs-scopethe-crux-parent-child-scope-having-modelwith-and-without-dot)