# Scope model is showing undefined value

Tags: angularjs

here is controller code which is called on textbox change event:

```
$scope.doAutoCompleteType = function() {
    $scope.suggestedItems.length = 0;
    var text = $scope.searchText;
    console.log("=========>"+text);
}
```

here is html code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type text.." ng-model="searchText" ng-change="doAutoCompleteType()">
```

problem is `console.log("=========>"+text);` is printing `undefined`

Comment: pass serchText in html ng-change="doAutoCompleteType(searchText)" and get it in script $scope.doAutoCompleteType = function(serchText)

Comment: Interesting, I've done this before and it works properly.   I guess if you have time create a jsfiddle example, my assumption is there's something else causing the problem.  Do you have an watchers or events that are manipulating that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$scope.doAutoCompleteType = function(text) {
    $scope.suggestedItems.length = 0;
    console.log("=========>"+text);
}


<input type="text" placeholder="Type text.." ng-model="searchText" ng-change="doAutoCompleteType(searchText)">
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your code as it is. Can you post more code? Here is an example with ng-change:

```
<body ng-app="changeExample">
 <script>
  angular.module('changeExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.change = function() {
        $scope.text2 = $scope.text;
        var print = $scope.text;
        console.log("***" + print);
      };
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-change="change()" id="ng-change-example1" /><br/>
  <tt>text2 = {{text2}}</tt><br/>
</div>
</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LVQqCIBW3kGpN4bIzVwK?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

it should be having either some typo mistake or parent child scope issue which is expalined in the below link

[angularjs scope(the crux): parent child scope having model(with and without 'dot')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820473/angularjs-scopethe-crux-parent-child-scope-having-modelwith-and-without-dot)